# Pandas, perf issues when filtering a dataframe, calculating on the filtered dataframe, and updating the main dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some performance issues with pandas. I have a quite big dataframe which contains about 3000 products, identified with a `unique_id` (and several entries per product). I need to filter the dataframe for each product, perform some calculations, and update the base dataframe. For now I'm doing something like that:

```
for unique_id in self.df.unique_id.unique():

    # prod_df = self.df[(self.df["unique_id"] == unique_id)]
    prod_df = self.df.query(f"unique_id == {unique_id}")

    some_function(prod_df)
```

And

```
def some_function(prod_df):

    ... some code ...

    values = some_values

    for idx, val in zip(prod_df.index, some_values):
        self.df.loc[idx, "foo_column"] = val
```

This code is however awfully slow (I'm talking several hours here...). I did some quick profiling and it seems my script spends most of its runtime in pandas `indexing.py` script. Not so much surprise here.

I was wondering if there is a pandas solution to this kind of problem. I think the filtering, and maybe also the writing values per index, are killing the perf of my script. Any idea? At this point I'm thinking putting my dataframe in a dict or in a sqlite database.

EDIT:

Here is a typical function that I could use in-lieu of `some_function`:

```
def comp_gradient_for_column(
    self, prod_df: pd.DataFrame
) -> None:

    """
    Compute the gradient for a given column and insert it in the dataframe

    Arguments:
        prod_df (pd.DataFrame): sub-dataframe to work on

    Returns:
        None:
    """

    values = prod_df[column_name].values
    gradients = np.gradient(values)

    for idx, val in zip(prod_df.index, gradients):
        self.df.loc[idx, "foo_column"] = val
```

Comment: Are the calculations *identical* for each product? Can you provide a [mcve]? Any answer is heavily dependent on whether the logic in `some_function` is vectorisable. Currently, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I sadly can't provide a working example, the code is confidential. But I can tell you that some code in `some_function` is vectorizable, yes, but not all of it. My question here is really on the filtering, because I need to work on the filtered dataframe in the non-vectorizable code. I'll however accept an answer on a vectorizable code. I added a typical function I could use in-lieu of `some_function` in my question.